# How to view multiple commit changes in a single window using meld?

Tags: git, meld

I have started to use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) as [git](https://git-scm.com/) difftool to view code changes between commits.

What I would like to do is to navigate between different commits in a single [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) window using **one tab per file** and making **any commit selectable through the drop-down menus**.

Using the image below as example, I want to display each file in the repository in a separate tab. In this case, my repository has *test1.txt* and *test2.txt* files.

In each tab, I want to be able to individually select any version/commit of that file so as to dynamically change the displayed file comparison.

[image: Meld GUI]

In that way it would be very easy to navigate through temporal changes in any of the modified files that are featured in a [git](https://git-scm.com/) repository.

Is there a way to **automatically** open a meld window with this layout when calling `git difftool` ?

Comment: gitk lets you browse the history of a file (or set of files) and launch meld for the diffs between any two revisions (they don't have to be consecutive).  The only thing this really lacks is the ability to launch one instance of meld for multiple files in a change set -- so you have to do that manually for each file of interest.